# Partition, transform, and then zip to new array with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this array of candidates. Some of them are removed, and some of them are not. They're unordered, and I want to order them by last name AND by whether or not they are removed. I'm using a pipe that accepts only arrays and orders them by a given property if the elements are objects.

This isn't difficult:

```
let added = this.candidates.filter(c => !c.removed);
let removed = this.candidates.filter(c => c.removed);

added = new OrderByPipe().transform(added, ['lastName']);
removed = new OrderByPipe().transform(removed, ['lastName']);

let orderedCandidates = added.concat(removed);
```

For my own self interest, I want to transform my candidates array to an observable and pipe it through `.partition()`

So far I've managed:

```
orderCandidates() {
    let [added, removed] = Observable.from(this.candidates)
        .partition(c => !c.removed);
    added = added.toArray().map(a => new OrderByPipe().transfrom(a, ['-lastName']));
    removed = removed.toArray().map(r => new OrderByPipe().transfrom(r, ['-lastName']));
}
```

Then I want to zip or concat my two sorted arrays into a new array. I recently learned that I have this image in my mind of everything in rxjs flowing through a very streamlined pipeline, and I feel that I run out of ideas when I try to conform to this image.

Comment: Downvotes without explanations aren't useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if your `orderedCandidates` is already a filtered **AND** sorted array, why not just create an observable from it, using `Observable.of()`?:

```
let added = this.candidates.filter(c => !c.removed);
let removed = this.candidates.filter(c => c.removed);

added = new OrderByPipe().transform(added, ['lastName']);
removed = new OrderByPipe().transform(removed, ['lastName']);

let orderedCandidates = added.concat(removed);

//create an Observable of list of ordered, sorted candidates
let orderedCandidates$ = Observable.of(orderedCandidates);
```

Or, if you are really in love with Observables and would want to **only** use Observable operators, then simply use `.map()` to transform your data:

```
orderCandidates() {
    let orderedCandidate$ = Observable.from(this.candidates)
        .partition(c => !c.removed)
        .map(([added, removed])=>{
            added = added.toArray().map(a => new OrderByPipe().transfrom(a, ['-lastName']));
            removed = removed.toArray().map(r => new OrderByPipe().transfrom(r, ['-lastName']));
            return added.concat(removed);
        })

    return orderedCandidate$;
}
```

Comment: I feel like I come at these things upside down. I can figure out where I am, and where I need to be, but not how to get there. Looking at your second example, I can tell I usually think of information flowing down and out the bottom, so I get tangled about what to do with my result down there. I always forget that things are returned to the top. I wish the learnrx site had about fifty more problems to solve! lol, thanks for the elegant explanation.

Comment: @wolfhoundjesse I know right! Once you taste the goodness of reactive programming, you cant help but to always do it the observable way :)